# Change node color depending on status

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on the below fiddle -

```js
var d3cola = cola.d3adaptor().convergenceThreshold(0.1);

var width = 960, height = 700;

var outer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
       .attr({ width: width, height: height, "pointer-events": "all" });

    outer.append('rect')
       .attr({ class: 'background', width: "100%", height: "100%" })
       .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function(d) {
          vis.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
       }));

var vis = outer
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(250,250) scale(0.3)');

     outer.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
         .attr({
                id: 'end-arrow',
                viewBox: '0 -5 10 10',
                refX: 8,
                markerWidth: 6,
                markerHeight: 6,
                orient: 'auto'
            })
          .append('svg:path')
            .attr({
                d: 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5L2,0',
                'stroke-width': '0px',
                fill: '#000'});
      //    .data(["approve", "reject"]);

      
    
var nodes = [
       { "nodes": "Initiate"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Send to Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of FA Rejection"},
{ "nodes": "Finance Approves"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of FA"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of RM Rejection"},
{ "nodes": "Reporting Manager Approves"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of RM"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill for RM"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill after WF Complete"},
{ "nodes": "Send Notification to Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on form for Finance"},
{ "nodes": "WF Completed Permissions on Attachments"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor Rejected by RM"},
{ "nodes": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-2"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by RM"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Attachments"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions-Tracking No. Folder"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill"},
{ "nodes": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-1"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by FA"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on form for Reporting Manager"},
{ "nodes": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder"},
{ "nodes": "WF Completed Permissions on Form"},
{ "nodes": "End"}
  ];

var edges = [

{ "source_name": "Update Comments of Requestor",     "target_name": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-1",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 1,  "target": 21},
{ "source_name": "Send to Requestor",     "target_name": "Update Comments of Requestor",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 16,  "target": 1},
{ "source_name": "Update Comments of FA Rejection",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by FA",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 8,  "target": 6},
{ "source_name": "Finance Approves",     "target_name": "Update Comments of FA Rejection",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 17,  "target": 8},
{ "source_name": "Update Comments of FA",     "target_name": "WF Completed Permissions on Form",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 13,  "target": 9},
{ "source_name": "Finance Approves",     "target_name": "Update Comments of FA",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 17,  "target": 13},
{ "source_name": "Update Comments of RM Rejection",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by RM",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 24,  "target": 10},
{ "source_name": "Reporting Manager Approves",     "target_name": "Update Comments of RM Rejection",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 19,  "target": 24},
{ "source_name": "Update Comments of RM",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Bill",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 11,  "target": 18},
{ "source_name": "Reporting Manager Approves",     "target_name": "Update Comments of RM",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 19,  "target": 11},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Bill for RM",     "target_name": "Reporting Manager Approves",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 12,  "target": 19},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Bill after WF Complete",     "target_name": "End",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 22,  "target": 2},
{ "source_name": "Send Notification to Requestor",     "target_name": "Finance Approves",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 23,  "target": 17},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on form for Finance",     "target_name": "Send Notification to Requestor",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 5,  "target": 23},
{ "source_name": "WF Completed Permissions on Attachments",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Bill after WF Complete",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 15,  "target": 22},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor Rejected by RM",     "target_name": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-2",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 4,  "target": 25},
{ "source_name": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-2",     "target_name": "Send to Requestor",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "dormant",  "source": 25,  "target": 16},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by RM",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor Rejected by RM",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 10,  "target": 4},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Attachments",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on form for Reporting Manager",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 20,  "target": 26},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions-Tracking No. Folder",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Attachments",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 0,  "target": 20},
{ "source_name": "Initiate",     "target_name": "Set Permissions-Tracking No. Folder",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 14,  "target": 0},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Bill",     "target_name": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 18,  "target": 3},
{ "source_name": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-1",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on form for Reporting Manager",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 21,  "target": 26},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor",     "target_name": "Send to Requestor",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "dormant",  "source": 7,  "target": 16},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by FA",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "dormant",  "source": 6,  "target": 7},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on form for Reporting Manager",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Bill for RM",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "pending",  "source": 26,  "target": 12},
{ "source_name": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on form for Finance",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "pending",  "source": 3,  "target": 5},
{ "source_name": "WF Completed Permissions on Form",     "target_name": "WF Completed Permissions on Attachments",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "pending",  "source": 9,  "target": 15}

  ];

 d3cola
       .avoidOverlaps(true)
       .convergenceThreshold(1e-3)
       .flowLayout('x', 150)
       .size([width, height])
       .nodes(nodes)
       .links(edges)
       .jaccardLinkLengths(150);

var link = vis.selectAll(".link")
             .data(edges)
             .enter().append("path")
            // .attr("class", "link")
             .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; });

var margin = 10, pad = 12;
var node = vis.selectAll(".node")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .classed("node", true)
            .attr({ rx: 5, ry: 5 })
            .call(d3cola.drag);

var label = vis.selectAll(".label")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .text(function (d) { return d.nodes; })
            .call(d3cola.drag)
            .each(function (d) {
                    var b = this.getBBox();
                    var extra = 2 * margin + 2 * pad;
                    d.width = b.width + extra;
                    d.height = b.height + extra;
             });

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
                .y(function (d) { return d.y; })
                .interpolate("linear");

var routeEdges = function () {
           d3cola.prepareEdgeRouting();
           link.attr("d", function (d) {
                 return lineFunction(d3cola.routeEdge(d));
           });
                if (isIE()) link.each(function (d) { this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this) });
            }
        d3cola.start(50, 100, 200).on("tick", function () {
              node.each(function (d) { d.innerBounds = d.bounds.inflate(-margin); })
                  .attr("x", function (d) { return d.innerBounds.x; })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.innerBounds.y; })
                    .attr("width", function (d) {
                        return d.innerBounds.width();
                    })
                    .attr("height", function (d) { return d.innerBounds.height(); });

                link.attr("d", function (d) {
                    cola.vpsc.makeEdgeBetween(d, d.source.innerBounds, d.target.innerBounds, 5);
                    var lineData = [{ x: d.sourceIntersection.x, y: d.sourceIntersection.y }, { x: d.arrowStart.x, y: d.arrowStart.y }];
                    
                    return lineFunction(lineData);
                });
                if (isIE()) link.each(function (d) { this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this) });

                label
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y + (margin + pad) / 2 });

            }).on("end", routeEdges);

        function isIE() { return ((navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') || ((navigator.appName == 'Netscape') && (new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})").exec(navigator.userAgent) != null))); }
```

```css
.background {
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        fill: white;
    }

    .node {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
        cursor: move;
        fill: lightcoral;
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 3px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        marker-end: url(#end-arrow);
    }

    .label {
        fill: black;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-anchor: middle;
        cursor: move;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/cola.v3.min.js"></script>E
```

I works fine. Now I need to change the color of the target node (rectangle) depending on 'status' attribute.

In order to achieve this, I create the below CSS classes -

```
.finished {
    fill: green;
}
.pending {
   fill: blue;
}
.dormant {
   fill: purple;
}
```

and changed

```
.classed("node", true)
```

to

```
.style("fill", function (d) { return d3.select(this).classed(edges[d.status], true)})
```

This resulted in all the nodes being colored black.

Can someone please help me identify the problem.

New fiddle is

```js
var d3cola = cola.d3adaptor().convergenceThreshold(0.1);

var width = 960, height = 700;

var outer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
       .attr({ width: width, height: height, "pointer-events": "all" });

    outer.append('rect')
       .attr({ class: 'background', width: "100%", height: "100%" })
       .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function(d) {
          vis.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
       }));

var vis = outer
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(250,250) scale(0.3)');

     outer.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
         .attr({
                id: 'end-arrow',
                viewBox: '0 -5 10 10',
                refX: 8,
                markerWidth: 6,
                markerHeight: 6,
                orient: 'auto'
            })
          .append('svg:path')
            .attr({
                d: 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5L2,0',
                'stroke-width': '0px',
                fill: '#000'});

      
    
var nodes = [
       { "nodes": "Initiate"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Send to Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of FA Rejection"},
{ "nodes": "Finance Approves"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of FA"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of RM Rejection"},
{ "nodes": "Reporting Manager Approves"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of RM"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill for RM"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill after WF Complete"},
{ "nodes": "Send Notification to Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on form for Finance"},
{ "nodes": "WF Completed Permissions on Attachments"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor Rejected by RM"},
{ "nodes": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-2"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by RM"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Attachments"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions-Tracking No. Folder"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill"},
{ "nodes": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-1"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by FA"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on form for Reporting Manager"},
{ "nodes": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder"},
{ "nodes": "WF Completed Permissions on Form"},
{ "nodes": "End"}
  ];

var edges = [

{ "source_name": "Update Comments of Requestor",     "target_name": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-1",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 1,  "target": 21},
{ "source_name": "Send to Requestor",     "target_name": "Update Comments of Requestor",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 16,  "target": 1},
{ "source_name": "Update Comments of FA Rejection",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by FA",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 8,  "target": 6},
{ "source_name": "Finance Approves",     "target_name": "Update Comments of FA Rejection",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 17,  "target": 8},
{ "source_name": "Update Comments of FA",     "target_name": "WF Completed Permissions on Form",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 13,  "target": 9},
{ "source_name": "Finance Approves",     "target_name": "Update Comments of FA",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 17,  "target": 13},
{ "source_name": "Update Comments of RM Rejection",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by RM",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 24,  "target": 10},
{ "source_name": "Reporting Manager Approves",     "target_name": "Update Comments of RM Rejection",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 19,  "target": 24},
{ "source_name": "Update Comments of RM",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Bill",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 11,  "target": 18},
{ "source_name": "Reporting Manager Approves",     "target_name": "Update Comments of RM",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 19,  "target": 11},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Bill for RM",     "target_name": "Reporting Manager Approves",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 12,  "target": 19},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Bill after WF Complete",     "target_name": "End",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 22,  "target": 2},
{ "source_name": "Send Notification to Requestor",     "target_name": "Finance Approves",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 23,  "target": 17},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on form for Finance",     "target_name": "Send Notification to Requestor",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 5,  "target": 23},
{ "source_name": "WF Completed Permissions on Attachments",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Bill after WF Complete",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 15,  "target": 22},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor Rejected by RM",     "target_name": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-2",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 4,  "target": 25},
{ "source_name": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-2",     "target_name": "Send to Requestor",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "dormant",  "source": 25,  "target": 16},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by RM",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor Rejected by RM",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 10,  "target": 4},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Attachments",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on form for Reporting Manager",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 20,  "target": 26},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions-Tracking No. Folder",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Attachments",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 0,  "target": 20},
{ "source_name": "Initiate",     "target_name": "Set Permissions-Tracking No. Folder",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 14,  "target": 0},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Bill",     "target_name": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 18,  "target": 3},
{ "source_name": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-1",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on form for Reporting Manager",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "finished",  "source": 21,  "target": 26},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor",     "target_name": "Send to Requestor",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "dormant",  "source": 7,  "target": 16},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by FA",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "dormant",  "source": 6,  "target": 7},
{ "source_name": "Set Permissions on form for Reporting Manager",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on Bill for RM",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "pending",  "source": 26,  "target": 12},
{ "source_name": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder",     "target_name": "Set Permissions on form for Finance",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "pending",  "source": 3,  "target": 5},
{ "source_name": "WF Completed Permissions on Form",     "target_name": "WF Completed Permissions on Attachments",     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "pending",  "source": 9,  "target": 15}

  ];

 d3cola
       .avoidOverlaps(true)
       .convergenceThreshold(1e-3)
       .flowLayout('x', 150)
       .size([width, height])
       .nodes(nodes)
       .links(edges)
       .jaccardLinkLengths(150);

var link = vis.selectAll(".link")
             .data(edges)
             .enter().append("path")
             .attr("class", "link");

var margin = 10, pad = 12;
var node = vis.selectAll(".node")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("rect")
           // .classed("node", true)
            .style("fill", function (d) { return d3.select(this).classed(edges[d.status], true)})
            .attr({ rx: 5, ry: 5 })
            .call(d3cola.drag);

var label = vis.selectAll(".label")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .text(function (d) { return d.nodes; })
            .call(d3cola.drag)
            .each(function (d) {
                    var b = this.getBBox();
                    var extra = 2 * margin + 2 * pad;
                    d.width = b.width + extra;
                    d.height = b.height + extra;
             });

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
                .y(function (d) { return d.y; })
                .interpolate("linear");

var routeEdges = function () {
           d3cola.prepareEdgeRouting();
           link.attr("d", function (d) {
                 return lineFunction(d3cola.routeEdge(d));
           });
                if (isIE()) link.each(function (d) { this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this) });
            }
        d3cola.start(50, 100, 200).on("tick", function () {
              node.each(function (d) { d.innerBounds = d.bounds.inflate(-margin); })
                  .attr("x", function (d) { return d.innerBounds.x; })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.innerBounds.y; })
                    .attr("width", function (d) {
                        return d.innerBounds.width();
                    })
                    .attr("height", function (d) { return d.innerBounds.height(); });

                link.attr("d", function (d) {
                    cola.vpsc.makeEdgeBetween(d, d.source.innerBounds, d.target.innerBounds, 5);
                    var lineData = [{ x: d.sourceIntersection.x, y: d.sourceIntersection.y }, { x: d.arrowStart.x, y: d.arrowStart.y }];
                    return lineFunction(lineData);
                });
                if (isIE()) link.each(function (d) { this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this) });

                label
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y + (margin + pad) / 2 });

            }).on("end", routeEdges);

        function isIE() { return ((navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') || ((navigator.appName == 'Netscape') && (new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})").exec(navigator.userAgent) != null))); }
```

```css
.background {
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        fill: white;
    }

    .node {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
        cursor: move;
        fill: lightcoral;
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 3px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        marker-end: url(#end-arrow);
    }

    .label {
        fill: black;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-anchor: middle;
        cursor: move;
    }

.finished {
    fill: green;
}
.pending {
    fill: blue;
}
.dormant {
    fill: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/cola.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to color the `nodes` by status, or the `edges` (aka links)? Right now you're code appears to be trying to color the `nodes`, even though only the `edges` have a `"status"` attribute.

Comment: I am trying to color the nodes based on the status of the edges. So if the edge status is 'finished' then the target node get colored as green. If the edge status is dormant, target node gets colored as purple, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, change your data structure so that `status` is part of the nodes array.  This makes things a bit easier.  If you can't you'll have to iterate the edges array to find the match to the nodes array:

```
var node = vis.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr('class',function(d){ //<-- don't need classed, attr is fine
    var N = edges.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++){
      if (edges[i].source_name === d.nodes){
        return edges[i].status; //<-- found it and return status
      }
    }
   })
  .attr({ rx: 5, ry: 5 })
  .call(d3cola.drag);
```

Updated [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/bQn4LIJ7MyTKN7iudxFM?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks Mark. Your recommendation makes perfect sense.